# Где граница бизнес-логики в контроллере?

Tags: php, mvc, шаблоны-проектирования

Разъясните, пожалуйста, что является бизнес логикой приложения и где ее границы с контроллером? Какой вариант более правильный и почему:  delete или deleteV2 ?

```
class ArticleController
{
    public function delete(int $articleId, ArticleService $service)
    {
        $article = $service->deleteById($articleId);
        $service->deleteImage($articleId);
        $service->deleteCache($articleId);
    }
    public function deleteV2(int $articleId, ArticleService $service)
    {
        $article = $service->deleteV2($articleId);
    }
}

class ArticleService
{
    public function delete(int $articleId)
    {
        $article = $repository->find($articleId);
        $repository->delete($article);
    }

    public function deleteV2(int $articleId)
    {
        $this->delete($articleId);
        $this->deleteImage($articleId);
        $this->deleteCache($articleId);
    }

    public function deleteImage(int $articleId)
    {
        //удаление изображения
    }

    public function deleteCache(int $articleId)
    {
        //удаление кэша
    }
}
```

Comment: А Delete у вас уже бизнес логика, v2 правильней. Сервис сам за все свои зависимости должен отвечать, просто потому что так проще и вам не надо проверять в контроллере а не забыл я что-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Контроллеры это уровень взаимодействия с пользователем(получение запроса) там бизнес логики быть не должно. На уровне сервиса бизнес логика может присутствовать.
2. Не так важно где у вас бизнес логика, важнее, что она должна быть вы одном месте. "Если вы не найдете место бизнес логике - она найдет его сама".

Второй вариант правильнее.